# How to get labels of model prediction in text format?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a model and I trained and saved it, now I just want to load it and then predict 1000 images file for me I load it by this code

```
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('dir')
```

and I use this code for predicting my data

```
loaded_model.predict(test_dataset)
```

this code gives me back a NumPy array, How can I get labels that predict in the `model. prediction` as a text file.

Comment: map string format to labels, join the text and save it to file, what is shape of your predictions ?

Comment: Neural networks work with numbers. So the output is always a number. If you have e.g. multi-class prediction, you may get the index of predicted class by `np.argmax(prediction)` then map the index to its corresponding class name, you have before.

Comment: It is a  NumPy array with a  shape of '(2600, 26)' @Nagakiran

Comment: `', '.join(list(array.astype(str).flatten()))` hope it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the string to numerals followed by joining into text

```
', '.join(list(array.astype(str).flatten()))

', '.join(array.astype(str).flatten().tolist()))
```